# ln: creating a symbolic link CUSTOM_TOP/file_name ( path) file exists shell script

Tags: shell, unix, oracle-apps

I have created a link in shell script by using

```
ln -fs $FND_TOP/bin/fndcpesr $CUSTOM_TOP/file_name
```

but its giving an error

```
ln: creating a symbolic link CUSTOM_TOP/file_name ( path) file exists
```

program exits with status 1.

No echo is getting printed in log

I am trying to create a host type executable in oracle apps

Comment: Does the error say `CUSTOM_TOP` literally? Or does it use the actual path in the `$CUSTOM_TOP` variable? Also is `( path)` literal?

Comment: You can refer this [Symbolic Link Creation](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/creating-soft-link-or-symbolic-link/)

Answer (score 0):

You have a wrong order of the params.
ln -s fileExists symbollinks.
In your case, ln -fs $CUSTOM_TOP/file_name $FND_TOP/bin/fndcpesr
Hope helps